# Backspace on Currency-Formatted EditText Causing Issues

Tags: android, formatting, textwatcher

All- I have an `edittext` that is formatted for currency like so:

[image]

The problem is when the user backspaces so there is only one numeral and than the dollar sign ($5) and than hits backspace one more time, my app force closes. I looked at the logcat and saw that it was caused by an invalid double ($) in my textwatcher which makes perfect sence when you look at my code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
        editText$.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,]", "");

            double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
            String formatted = formatter.format(parsed);

            current = formatted;

            editText$.setText(formatted);
            editText$.setSelection(formatted.length());
            editText$.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

I tried to use an "if" statement inside of the textwatcher to catch if only the dollar sign was left before it went through the formatting but no luck there. Does anybody know of a work around for this problem? Thanks.